# How to display a description of a table in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to display description of a table in Oracle SQL like below. How can I do that?

I have tried `SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COMMENTS WHERE table_name = 'abc'` but that is not the SQL command for get the the output like below.

```
Name        Type        Nullable    Default Id  Comments
------- ----------- ------------    ---------   ---------
ABC     VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL    1   
PQR     VARCHAR2(2000)  NOT NULL    2   
XYZ     VARCHAR2(30)                3
```

Answer (score 3):

The thing you look for is probably [sqlplus's describe](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12019.htm).

You could also see the results from:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_tab_columns
 WHERE table_name = 'abc';
```

Answer (score 2):

As you want some column data along with its **comment**, you'll have to join `user_tab_columns` and `user_col_comments`.

This is just an example; improve it, if you want:

```
SQL>   SELECT a.column_name,
  2              a.data_type
  3           || CASE
  4                 WHEN a.data_type = 'NUMBER'
  5                 THEN
  6                    CASE
  7                       WHEN     a.data_precision IS NULL
  8                            AND a.data_scale IS NULL
  9                       THEN
 10                          NULL
 11                       ELSE
 12                             '('
 13                          || TO_CHAR (a.data_precision)
 14                          || ', '
 15                          || TO_CHAR (a.data_scale)
 16                          || ')'
 17                    END
 18                 WHEN a.data_type LIKE '%CHAR%'
 19                 THEN
 20                    '(' || TO_CHAR (a.data_length) || ')'
 21                 ELSE
 22                    NULL
 23              END data_type,
 24           a.nullable,
 25           a.column_id,
 26           b.comments
 27      FROM user_tab_columns a
 28           LEFT JOIN user_col_comments b
 29              ON     a.table_name = b.table_name
 30                 AND a.column_name = b.column_name
 31     WHERE a.table_name = 'GOPLAN'
 32  ORDER BY a.column_id;
```

Result:

```
COLUMN_NAME                    DATA_TYPE            N  COLUMN_ID COMMENTS
------------------------------ -------------------- - ---------- --------------------------------------------------
ID_GO_PLAN                     NUMBER               N          1
ID_OSOBA                       NUMBER               N          2 Person ID
GODINA                         NUMBER(4, 0)         N          3 
BROJ_DANA_GO                   NUMBER               N          4 Total number of days
CB_GOTOVO                      NUMBER(1, 0)         N          5 Is the plan verified?
CB_ODOBREN                     NUMBER(1, 0)         N          6 Manager has approved the plan
DATUM_ODOBRENJA                DATE                 Y          7 When did manager approve it?
NAPOMENA_ODOBRENJE             VARCHAR2(200)        Y          8 Additional note

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use Describe command:**

```
DESCRIBE { table-Name | view-Name }
```

**Description**

Command provides a description of the specified table or view. For a list of tables in the current schema, use the `Show Tables` command. For a list of views in the current schema, use the `Show Views` command. For a list of available schemas, use the `Show Schemas` command.

If the table or view is in a particular schema, qualify it with the schema name.

If the table or view name is case-sensitive, enclose it in single quotes.

You can display all the columns from all the tables and views in a single schema in a single display by using the wildcard character `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Not a SQL command, but an updated version of DESC[ribe], called INFO[rmation]

Provided by both SQL Developer and SQLcl -

```
SQL> info locations
TABLE: LOCATIONS 
     LAST ANALYZED:2021-10-10 10:42:07.0 
     ROWS         :23 
     SAMPLE SIZE  :23 
     INMEMORY     :DISABLED 
     COMMENTS     :Locations table that contains specific address of a specific office,
                       warehouse, and/or production site of a company. Does not store addresses /
                       locations of customers. Contains 23 rows; references with the
                       departments and countries tables.  

Columns 
NAME             DATA TYPE           NULL  DEFAULT    COMMENTS
*LOCATION_ID     NUMBER(4,0)         No               Primary key of locations table
 STREET_ADDRESS  VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)   Yes              Street address of an office, warehouse, or
                                                      production site of a company.Contains building
                                                      number and street name
 POSTAL_CODE     VARCHAR2(12 BYTE)   Yes              Postal code of the location of an office,
                                                      warehouse, or production siteof a company. 
 CITY            VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)   No               A not null column that shows city where an office,
                                                      warehouse, orproduction site of a company is
                                                      located. 
 STATE_PROVINCE  VARCHAR2(25 BYTE)   Yes              State or Province where an office, warehouse, or
                                                      production site of acompany is located.
 COUNTRY_ID      CHAR(2 BYTE)        Yes              Country where an office, warehouse, or production
                                                      site of a company islocated. Foreign key to
                                                      country_id column of the countries table.

Indexes
HR.LOC_ID_PK                UNIQUE        VALID                       LOCATION_ID       HR.LOC_CITY_IX              NONUNIQUE     VALID                       CITY              HR.LOC_COUNTRY_IX           NONUNIQUE     VALID                       COUNTRY_ID        HR.LOC_STATE_PROVINCE_IX    NONUNIQUE     VALID                       STATE_PROVINCE    

References
DEPARTMENTS    DEPT_LOC_FK        NO ACTION      ENABLED    NOT DEFERRABLE    VALIDATED    USER NAME    
SQL>
```

If you'd rather have column stats vs comments, you can do INFO+

```
SQL> info+ locations
TABLE: LOCATIONS 
     LAST ANALYZED:2021-10-10 10:42:07.0 
     ROWS         :23 
     SAMPLE SIZE  :23 
     INMEMORY     :DISABLED 
     COMMENTS     :Locations table that contains specific address of a specific office,
                       warehouse, and/or production site of a company. Does not store addresses /
                       locations of customers. Contains 23 rows; references with the
                       departments and countries tables.  

Columns 
NAME             DATA TYPE           NULL  DEFAULT    LOW_VALUE               HIGH_VALUE              NUM_DISTINCT   HISTOGRAM  
*LOCATION_ID     NUMBER(4,0)         No                   1000                    3200                    23             NONE       
 STREET_ADDRESS  VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)   Yes                  12-98 Victoria Street   Schwanthalerstr. 7031   23             NONE       
 POSTAL_CODE     VARCHAR2(12 BYTE)   Yes                  00989                   YSW 9T2                 22             NONE       
 CITY            VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)   No                   Beijing                 Whitehorse              23             NONE       
 STATE_PROVINCE  VARCHAR2(25 BYTE)   Yes                  BE                      Yukon                   17             NONE       
 COUNTRY_ID      CHAR(2 BYTE)        Yes                                                                  14             NONE       

Indexes
HR.LOC_ID_PK                UNIQUE        VALID                       LOCATION_ID       HR.LOC_CITY_IX              NONUNIQUE     VALID                       CITY              HR.LOC_COUNTRY_IX           NONUNIQUE     VALID                       COUNTRY_ID        HR.LOC_STATE_PROVINCE_IX    NONUNIQUE     VALID                       STATE_PROVINCE    

References
DEPARTMENTS    DEPT_LOC_FK        NO ACTION      ENABLED    NOT DEFERRABLE    VALIDATED    USER NAME    
SQL>
```

SQLcl has been part of the Oracle Database install (server and client) for some time, but it also available via free license [here](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqlcl-downloads.html)

Run the same command in SQLDev -
[image]

*Disclaimer: I'm the product manager at Oracle for our database tools including SQLcl and SQL Developer*